# filter the List and also take an extra element

Tags: c#, linq

```
class xyz
{
DateTime TimeStamp;
String a;
}
```

I have a list and I need to filter it using a where clause but also take one previous element. Example

```
listVariable.OrderBy(x=>x.TimeStamp).Where(x => x.Timestamp >= 
StartDateTime.LocalDateTime && x.Timestamp < 
EndDateTime.LocalDateTime).ToList();
```

I need the items to meet the condition mentioned above and also I need to take one extra previous element(i.e element before meeting this condition 
x => x.Timestamp >= StartDateTime.LocalDateTime). How can I achieve this?

Eg: The list contains elements like 
'09/11/2018'
'10/11/2018'
'15/11/2018'
'18/11/2018'
'21/11/2018'
'25/11/2018'

and if I query for dates between 18-20. I should get 
'15/11/2018' -> One previous extra element
'18/11/2018' '20/11/2018' -> these are those that met where(...) condition.

Comment: just an idea, but if you also do the opposite of your filter you will be left with another list from which you can then take / copy from?

Comment: I came up with this:                                                                                             
    `var nearest = Listvariable.MinBy(date => Math.Abs((date.Timestamp - 
    StartDateTime.LocalDateTime).Ticks)).FirstOrDefault(); `                                           
    `ListVariable.Where(x => x.Timestamp >= StartDateTime.LocalDateTime 
    && x.Timestamp < EndDateTime.LocalDateTime).Append(nearest)      
    .OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

You can make two collections and then union them:

```
var list1 = listVariable.OrderBy(x=>x.TimeStamp).Where(x => x.Timestamp >= 
                                         StartDateTime.LocalDateTime && x.Timestamp < 
                                         EndDateTime.LocalDateTime).ToList();
var minItem = list1.Min(x=>x.TimeStamp);

var list2 = listVariable.Where(x.Timestamp < minItem.LocalDateTime).OrderBy(x=>x.TimeStamp).First();

var finalList = list.Concat(list2);
```

Comment: this will fail if list1 includes the first element in (the ordered) listVariable right?

Comment: @KMoussa yes, those edge cases needs to be handled, this is to give an idea how the previous element could be determined

Comment: Thanks @EhsanSajjad.But, I can't use an extra list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [MoreLinq](http://%20http://morelinq.github.io) Library

It has Lead and Lag functions for this purpose.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Lag<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    int offset,
    TSource defaultLagValue,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387702/1118978)

please also note that this process is resource intensive

Comment: And how to use those?

Comment: @Simonare, Could you please share some examples?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this I write my own simple extension method (because it's fun and cuts dependencies on external libraries).

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SkipButOneWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var hasLeading = false;
            var leading = default(T);
            T current;
            while (true)
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) yield break;
                current = e.Current;
                if (predicate(current))
                {
                    hasLeading = true;
                    leading = current;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }

            if (hasLeading)
                yield return leading;
            yield return current;

            while (e.MoveNext())
                yield return e.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
listVariable
    .OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)
    .SkipButOneWhile(x => x.TimeStamp < start)
    .TakeWhile(x => x.TimeStamp < end)
    .ToList();
```

(Note: if you know it's sorted, which you do, `TakeWhile` is more efficient than `Where` as it allows to stop enumeration as soon as you cross the end date.)

Comment: Thanks @tinudu. This should work. Also, I found an alternate as shown below. 
    `listVariable.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
    .TakeUntil(x => x.Timestamp < StartDateTime.LocalDateTime).                             
    OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp).ToList();`                                                                                        TakeUnitl can be found in MoreLinq